# Nested tabs required, tabactivity vs viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have to create android layouts that have the below structure :

```
TabHost |
        MainActivity1
        |
        |--TabHost--|SubActivity 1
                    |SubActivity 2
        MainActivity2
        |
        |--TabHost--|SubActivity 1
                    |SubActivity 2
        MainActivity3
        |
        |--TabHost--|SubActivity 1
                    |SubActivity 2
```

I have currently implemented this structure using the deprecated TabHost/TabActivity/LocalActivityManager, but I am now facing problems like in one of the activities I need the camera to be invoked from a SubActivity and due to this structure onActivityResult doesnt return to the correct subactivity resulting in loss of the picture data taken. I am moving to Fragments and View Pager and hope to overcome these errors. The question is whether implementing ViewPager inside another ViewPager a good idea ? If not then how do we achieve tabs inside tabs ?

P.S. I need an interface similar to instagram profile, main activity in tabs and sections in tabs as well. Please refer the attached picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're gonna use `ViewPager`, and it is most often used in conjunction with `Fragment` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`, I think that you will not run into any problems if one of the fragments contains another `ViewPager` or anything else. That's the beauty of fragments, in my opinion.

Maybe you will run into some problems regarding the swype gesture, but I guess you can disable it in one of the ViewPagers.